# setting up nested X sessions with Xephyr properly (and securely)

Tags: security, lxde, x-server, xephyr

I am trying to set up `Xephyr` properly and securely, so that I can run another (nested) instance of `LXDE` under a different user inside my primary `LXDE` session.

I would like to use this nested session to browse potentially dangerous (malicious) websites under a test user account. I can delete the test user account after each session.

Lets suppose, my primary user is `martin` and I am logged into `LXDE`. I want to run a second (nested) `LXDE` session as user `martin-test`. I execute following commands:

```
Xephyr -ac -screen 1280x1024 -br -reset -terminate 2> /dev/null :1 &

DISPLAY=:1

su - martin-test -c 'startlxde'
```

Now a window has opened with new `LXDE` session.

But I am not sure what are the security implications. With `Xephyr -ac`, I have disabled access control. Have I just allowed anybody to connect to my Xserver ?

is this setup secure ?

How can I do it cleanly a properly?